# Dual monitor full screen game tabing out

Tags: windows-10, display, fullscreen

I have a two-monitor setup and when I have a fullscreen game and I use the other monitor it tabs out of the game and I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 3):

It depends a lot on the game, but this is normal behaviour for games that are set to set to use the exclusive "Fullscreen" mode.

If you don't want the game to minimise then you need to go into the game settings and choose one of the following settings which can use full screen, but as a conventional application window rather than exclusive fullscreen.

- Windowed borderless
- Fullscreen (windowed)
- Windowed

Make sure that the game resolution matches your monitor.

If your game has only a "windowed" mode then the program [Borderless Gaming](https://store.steampowered.com/app/388080/Borderless_Gaming/) can toggle the game to use the "windowed borderless" mode instead. The application is available for free on Github via the linked page, but is relatively cheap and it does a great job, particularly with games that are ported from console and can have problems if they are not running as an exclusive fullscreen application. I am not affiliated with Borderless Gaming, I am just a happy customer.

Note that exclusive fullscreen (the one that minimises when you tab out) *may* be slightly faster for gaming. In practice you probably won't notice.

Comment: Came here to give an answer. This trumped anything I could come up with!

Answer (score 1):

don't listen to ppl saying that it can't be done with exclusive fullscreen. the real issue is that when you alt-tab it continues to place the mouse positioning on your primary monitor, which now is going to be below the fullscreen application, bringing your desktop to the front layer of windows.

if you change your primary monitor to the non-game monitor while playing, you should be able to alt-tab without the game minimizing, and you'll clearly be able to see where it repositions your mouse and by doing so explain what was causing it to minimize before.......

i have an autohotkey script i use to swap primary display and also launch my game(s) and another event trigger in the autohotkey script to swap primary display back when it sees the game executable terminate.

there's also a feature in Steam's "Big Picture" mode that allows you to specify which monitor you want to be your primary while gaming.  It's designed to switch your primary to a different monitor for gaming then restore it when complete. But you can use it for the opposite also by specifying the non-game monitor as the one you're going to game on and simply moving the full screen game back to the other monitor with alt-enter then win-shift-left/right then another alt-enter..

then when you're done with the game, steam will automatically swap your primary monitor back to where it was.

hope this helps.